# Where i can download package for python to windows (offline installing)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This is code work when regression, but not work when classification

> import pandas as pd
>       import xgboost as xgb
>       import numpy as np
>       import itertools

```
salesPath = "E:\\python\\Salesprog\\"

test = pd.read_excel(salesPath + 'test.xlsx')
test.describe()

def latinizator(letter, dic):
    for i, j in dic.items():
        letter = letter.replace(i, j)
    return letter
>
```

This is latinizator, and it work good

```
>
legend = {
'а':'a',
'б':'b',
'в':'v',
'г':'g',
'д':'d',
'е':'e',
'ё':'yo',
'ж':'zh',
'з':'z',
'и':'i',
'й':'y',
'к':'k',
'л':'l',
'м':'m',
'н':'n',
'о':'o',
'п':'p',
'р':'r',
'с':'s',
'т':'t',
'у':'u',
'ф':'f',
'х':'h',
'ц':'ts',
'ч':'ch',
'ш':'sh',
'щ':'shch',
'ъ':'y',
'ы':'y',
'ь':"'",
'э':'e',
'ю':'yu',
'я':'ya',

'А':'A',
'Б':'B',
'В':'V',
'Г':'G',
'Д':'D',
'Е':'E',
'Ё':'Yo',
'Ж':'Zh',
'З':'Z',
'И':'I',
'Й':'Y',
'К':'K',
'Л':'L',
'М':'M',
'Н':'N',
'О':'O',
'П':'P',
'Р':'R',
'С':'S',
'Т':'T',
'У':'U',
'Ф':'F',
'Х':'H',
'Ц':'Ts',
'Ч':'Ch',
'Ш':'Sh',
'Щ':'Shch',
'Ъ':'Y',
'Ы':'Y',
'Ь':"'",
'Э':'E',
'Ю':'Yu',
'Я':'Ya',
}
phrases = []
for line in test['column_10']:
        phrases.append(latinizator(line, legend))
phrases = pd.DataFrame(phrases, columns = {'column_10'})
```

this is xgb regressor, but when classificator, dont work

```
>
test_y = test[['y_1','y_2','y_3','y_4']]
test_x = test.drop(['column_10','y_1','y_2','y_3','y_4'], axis=1)
test_x_exp2 = test_x**2
for i in list(test_x_exp2):
    test_x_exp2.rename(columns = {i:i+'exp2'}, inplace = True)
test_x_exp3 = test_x**3
for i in list(test_x_exp3):
    test_x_exp3.rename(columns = {i:i+'exp3'}, inplace = True)
test_x_exp4 = test_x**4
for i in list(test_x_exp4):
    test_x_exp4.rename(columns = {i:i+'exp4'}, inplace = True)
test_x_exp12 = test_x**(1/2)
for i in list(test_x_exp12):
    test_x_exp12.rename(columns = {i:i+'exp12'}, inplace = True)
test_x_log = np.log2(test_x)
for i in list(test_x_log):
    test_x_log.rename(columns = {i:i+'log'}, inplace = True)
test_x_sin = np.sin(test_x)
for i in list(test_x_sin):
    test_x_sin.rename(columns = {i:i+'sin'}, inplace = True)
test_x_cos = np.cos(test_x)
for i in list(test_x_cos):
    test_x_cos.rename(columns = {i:i+'cos'}, inplace = True)
summ = test_x 
b = []    
for i in range(2,9):
    for j in list(itertools.combinations(['column_1','column_2','column_4', 'column_5', 'column_6','column_7','column_8','column_9'],i)):
        b.append(j)
for i in b:
    a = 0
    nazv = ''
    for j in i:
        nazv = nazv + str(j)
        a = a + test_x[''+str(j)+'']
    a = pd.DataFrame(a, columns={nazv + 'plus'})    
    summ = summ.join(a)
for i in b:
    a = 0
    nazv = ''
    for j in i:
        nazv = nazv + str(j)
        a = a * test_x[''+str(j)+'']
    a = pd.DataFrame(a, columns={nazv + 'multi'})    
    summ = summ.join(a)
summ = summ.join(test_x_exp2).join(test_x_exp3).join(test_x_exp4).join(test_x_exp12).join(test_x_log).join(test_x_cos).join(test_x_sin)
```

cat_feat thisi is line

```
cat_feat = ['column_10']
one_hot = pd.get_dummies(phrases['column_10'])
rdf = summ.join(one_hot)
rdf = rdf.join(test_y[['y_2']])
rdf = rdf.join(test_y[['y_1']])

pd.set_option("display.max_columns",100)
rdf.corr()[rdf.corr() > 0.1]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
trg = test_y[['y_2']]
trn = rdf.drop(['y_1','y_2'], axis=1)


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(trn, trg, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

xgb_model = xgb.XGBRegressor()


cv = 10
#First step
alpha=[i for i in range(40, 600, 20)]
xgb_params  = [
    {
    "n_estimators": alpha
    }
]
#nacenka.to_excel(salesPath + 'nacenka111.xlsx')
xgb_grid = GridSearchCV(xgb_model, xgb_params, scoring='r2', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1, verbose=2)
xgb_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Other rezult

```
#First result check
xgb_best = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=xgb_grid.best_params_['n_estimators'])
xgb_best.fit(X_train, y_train)
best_predictions = xgb_best.predict(X_test)
r2_score(y_test, best_predictions)
best_predictions1 = pd.DataFrame(best_predictions)

r2_score(y_test, xgb_grid.predict(X_test))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
pred = xgb_best.booster().get_score(importance_type='weight')
print(xgb_best.booster().get_score(importance_type='weight'))
df = pd.DataFrame([pred])
df.plot(kind='bar')

#Second step
alpha1=[i for i in range(3, 10, 2)]
alpha2=[i for i in range(1, 6, 1)]
xgb_params  = [
    {
    "learning_rate": [0.1],
    "n_estimators": [xgb_grid.best_params_['n_estimators']],
    "max_depth": alpha1,
    "min_child_weight": alpha2
    }
]
xgb_grid = GridSearchCV(xgb_model, xgb_params, scoring='r2', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1, verbose=3)
xgb_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(xgb_grid.best_params_)

#Third step
# step 2b - tuning max_depth and min_child_weight
xgb_params  = [
    {
    "learning_rate": [0.1],
    "n_estimators": [xgb_grid.best_params_['n_estimators']],
    "max_depth": [xgb_grid.best_params_['max_depth']-1, xgb_grid.best_params_['max_depth'], xgb_grid.best_params_['max_depth']+1],
    "min_child_weight": [xgb_grid.best_params_['min_child_weight']-1, xgb_grid.best_params_['min_child_weight'], xgb_grid.best_params_['min_child_weight']+1]
    }
]

xgb_grid = GridSearchCV(xgb_model, xgb_params, scoring='r2', cv=cv, n_jobs=4, verbose=3)
xgb_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(xgb_grid.best_params_)

#Fourth step tuning gamma
xgb_params  = [
    {
    "learning_rate": [0.1],
    "n_estimators": [xgb_grid.best_params_['n_estimators']],
    "max_depth": [xgb_grid.best_params_['max_depth']],
    "min_child_weight": [xgb_grid.best_params_['min_child_weight']],
    "gamma": [i/10.0 for i in range(0,5)]
    }
]

xgb_grid = GridSearchCV(xgb_model, xgb_params, scoring='r2', cv=cv, n_jobs=4, verbose=3)
xgb_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(xgb_grid.best_params_)

## step 4 - tuning subsample, colsample_bytree
xgb_params  = [
    {
    "learning_rate": [0.1],
    "n_estimators": [xgb_grid.best_params_['n_estimators']],
    "max_depth": [xgb_grid.best_params_['max_depth']],
    "min_child_weight": [xgb_grid.best_params_['min_child_weight']],
    "gamma": [xgb_grid.best_params_['gamma']],
    "subsample": [i/10.0 for i in range(6,10)],
    "colsample_bytree": [i/10.0 for i in range(6,10)]
    }
]

xgb_grid = GridSearchCV(xgb_model, xgb_params, scoring='r2', cv=cv, n_jobs=4, verbose=3)
xgb_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(xgb_grid.best_params_)

# step 5a - tuning regularization
xgb_params  = [
    {
    "learning_rate": [0.1],
    "n_estimators": [xgb_grid.best_params_['n_estimators']],
    "max_depth": [xgb_grid.best_params_['max_depth']],
    "min_child_weight": [xgb_grid.best_params_['min_child_weight']],
    "gamma": [xgb_grid.best_params_['gamma']],
    "subsample": [xgb_grid.best_params_['subsample']],
    "colsample_bytree": [xgb_grid.best_params_['colsample_bytree']],
    'reg_alpha': [1e-5, 0, 0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 1e-05, 0.05, 0.1, 1, 2, 5, 10, 100]
    }
]

xgb_grid = GridSearchCV(xgb_model, xgb_params, scoring='r2', cv=cv, n_jobs=4, verbose=3)
xgb_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(xgb_grid.best_params_)

#Получаем параметры согласно обученной модели
xgb_best = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=xgb_grid.best_params_['n_estimators'],
                              learning_rate=0.1,
                              max_depth=6, 
                              min_child_weight=8,
                              gamma=xgb_grid.best_params_['gamma'], 
                              subsample=xgb_grid.best_params_['subsample'], 
                              colsample_bytree=xgb_grid.best_params_['colsample_bytree'], 
                              reg_alpha=xgb_grid.best_params_['reg_alpha'])
xgb_best.fit(X_train, y_train)

r2_score(y_test, xgb_best.predict(X_test))
```

when regressor start have problem with classificator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the packages are available at https://pypi.python.org/pypi
Click on the following link to download the corresponding packages:

1. matplotlib - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib

Answer (score 1):

Any search engine would have pointed you to:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

There you can download the [wheel](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html) files, which you can then install using the `pip` tool locally. If your company prevents access to that site, download the needed packages somewhere else. Be careful to check the dependencies of those packages and also download additional packages.

For windows, an alternative is the [Unofficial Windows Binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) by Christoph Gohlke.

P.S.: [sys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#module-sys) and [warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#module-warnings) are always available.

Comment: I think the op's question is he can't use pip to get package

Comment: The question states that the internet access is prohibited, not the use of the pip tool. This downloading the packages somewhere else and installing from the wheel-files should work.

Comment: hmm, then this maybe better than just download the folder of the module, since pip could manage dependency stuff for us, will delete my answer :D

Comment: @armnotstrong when using pip to install from a local file, dependencies must be present as a local file, too - otherwise `pip` will try to download it - I think your answer is a viable way, you should restore it.

Answer (score 1):

Python package management toolkit like `easy_instsall` and `pip` just download the package folder with executable python code to your local folder which is contained by the module search path and manage the dependency.

You could just get the source file of specific module you need and put in your working directory and you are good to go

For example, you could just

`git clone https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git numpy`

to put `numpy` in your project once you download that as a folder in your project (or maybe you'd like to download that with another machine able to connect the internet and copy that folder with an usb drive or something)

More over, this [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) about the Python library search path maybe help you to understand all the stuff under hook

**You should be careful about the dependency stuff by this way though.**

Answer (score 1):

I would definately have a look at Anaconda. https://www.continuum.io/downloads

List of packages included:
https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs

From what I can see the only package not included is "warnings".